# How do I make sure that a large 3D texture is only uploaded once to GPU in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

I have a large 3D texture that is used in multiple THREE.scenes / THREE.WebGLRenderers.

Do I have to use one shared THREE.DataTexture3D or one shared THREE.ShaderMaterial to avoid multiple memory consumption on GPU?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to share WebGL resources like textures, buffers or shader programs across different WebGL contexts. So if you have an instance of `THREE.DataTexture3D`, each instance of `THREE.WebGLRenderer` will create an own internal `WebGLTexture` object and upload the respective texture data to the GPU. So in this setup, it's actually not possible to save GPU memory.

Comment: That is really a problem in our case. Is that a limitation of WebGL or of THREE.js?